# Visual Studio: Shortcut to close window not working

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut

I changed the shortcut to close a window to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and to close all windows to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. Close all windows works fine, but <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> selects the word currently under the cursor but does not close the window.

When I right-click a tab it say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> is the shortcut to close it (And also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close all). Why is only the close window shortcut not working?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In Visual Studio (VS 2015 in my case but it's similar down to VS 2010 at least) keyboard shortcuts may have a different meaning depending on the context in which they are executed.

Click Tools / Options / Environment / Keyboard to look up or define shortcuts (you already did that probably). What I called "context" is selected in the combobox labelled "Use new shortcut in:". Most likely you defined the shortcut in "Global" but you want it to work in "Text Editor". In the latter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> selects the current word.

Redefine <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> for "Text Editor" and you should be fine.

Comment: How would I assign the Ctrl+W (great, <kbd> doesn‘t work in comments -.-) shortcut to also work in the properties editor (the one where I open the properties for a project) and also all other editors that are opened as tab? Do I really have to assign a shortcut for all of them by hand?

Answer (score 24):

I am using `Visual Studio 2017` & `Visual Studio 2019` and tried the answer from @TobiMcNamobi but it didn't work for me. After few such tries I got it work with below steps.

You should add it as `Global` shourtcut otherwise it will not work for `Designer` views.

1. Add <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> as a `Global` shortcut for `Window.CloseDocumentWindow`
2. Remove the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> shortcut for `Edit.SelectCurrentWord`

Comment: What's the difference from Window.Close?

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2019 it is Ctrl-F4 by default to CloseDocumentWindow. The action is Window.CloseDocumentWindow. I know this is old but the accepted answer has you change the short-cut key instead. I would rather use the default option.

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

[image]

If you're ever unsure go to the path above and you will see the image above then you can click inside the box "Press shortcut key" at the bottom of the form and type the short cut key you're interested in and it will tell you if it is used and what it is currently used for.

You can also reference the docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2022, make sure you also remove `Ctrl+W` from `selectCurrentWord` command.

Answer (score 0):

**2021:** For Visual Studio 2019:

See: https://gist.github.com/jpoehls/2030795#gistcomment-2335647

In my case, I had to existing assignments that I had to remove.  Thereafter, I could use the hotkey.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the tabs were **not** closing because I am using **Vim extension**. I had to add the following lines to Vim settings:

```
"vim.handleKeys": {
    "<C-w>": false
}
```

Just press Ctrl + , or Command + , for Mac users, search for Vim and go into Edit in settings.json as the following picture shows:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EjxL.png)

Answer (score -1):

In my VS Pro 2019, on Tools / Options / Environment / Keyboard, the first line offers using  a premade keyboard mapping scheme, with a drop-down option for VSCode keyborad mapping theme.

I picked it and it seems to have adopted the keyboard shortcuts I was used to from working on VSCode, Ctrl+W included.

Comment: The accepted answers describes the same solution.

Answer (score -2):

For those using linux with VSCode v1.56.2,

`File` --> `Preferences` --> `Keyboard Shortcuts`.

Search for `View:Close Editor` and as mentioned above, remove any keybinding that has the keybinding you want.

Comment: The question is regarding visual studio only.